# java.security.PrivilegedActionException while hitting webservices over https

Tags: java, web-services

I am getting the following exception, when i am trying to hit the webservice over https  using java client:

com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.client.p2p.HttpSOAPConnection post
SEVERE: SAAJ0009: Message send failed
com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: java.security.PrivilegedActionException: com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: Message send failed
    at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.client.p2p.HttpSOAPConnection.call(HttpSOAPConnection.java:157)
    at

Also if i use the same code for http , it works fine. Webservices are deployed on weblogic server.
Could anyone help me in resolving the issue.

Regards
Gurleen.

Answer (score 0):

The exception says that message cannot be sent.
Is it a firewall problem like for the same question here : http://www.coderanch.com/t/223309/Web-Services/java/Sending-Soap-requests-thru-Https